# how to deploy npm package to package registry of another group

Tags: npm, gitlab

I have a private repository that is placed under a GroupA (`GroupA/projectA`) and the package is deployed to its package registry. Fine, I'm able to download the package with my personal auth token. Now I want to deploy it to another package registry of GroupB(public).

Is it possible in GitLab to publish the same project as the npm package in another GroupB package registry without creating new repo in groupB? if yes then what could be my publicConfig value in package.json and .npmrc.